# Prove for any postive $k$,such $2^m-2^n|k^m-k^n$

Tags: number-theory

Let positive integers such $m>n$,and if $$2^m-2^n|3^m-3^n$$
then for any positive integers $k$ have
$$2^m-2^n|k^m-k^n$$

I have looked at the simpler case $k=1,2,3$.I was able to solve this,How to prove $k\ge 4$. Any progress on the problem is welcome.

Comment: Surely this does not hold for $k=1$? Shouldn't this be for $k\ge2$?

Comment: @Mufasa Is not zero divisible by every number?

Comment: @ChadShin - Oops! Sorry I misread this as the other way around - thanks for clarifying

Comment: Could anyone give me $(m,n)$ such that $m-n$ is not 2 or 1?

Comment: $(m,n)=(5,1)$ and $(m.n)=(8,2)$ are examples of pairs with such a property. It also follows from Little Fermat and such that the claim works for all $k$ for those pairs.

Comment: But, I'm also getting a deja vu vibe. Have we seen this before on our site?

Comment: FWIW I did a small Mathematica search. If $1\le n\le 100$ and $n<m\le n+100$, then the only pairs that work are $$(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(2,4),(2,6),(2,8),(2,14),(3,5),(3,7),(3,9),(3,15),(4,8),(4,16).$$ If that list is complete proving the claim is easy, because no prime factor $>13$ occurs as a factor of $2^m-2^n$ in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

There are only finitely many of $(m,n)$'s for which $2^m-2^n|k^m-k^n$ holds for all $k$ (as observed also by Jyrki in comments). 
This is proven in paper by Sun Qi and Zhang Ming-Zhi [*Pairs where $2^a - 2^b$ divides $n^a - n^b$ for all $n$*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1985-093-02/S0002-9939-1985-0770523-6/S0002-9939-1985-0770523-6.pdf), where they show that only $(m,n)$ for which this holds with $0 \leq n < m$ are:

$$
(1,0),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2),(5,3),(5,1),(6, 2), (7, 3),
(8, 4), (8, 2), (9, 3), (14, 2), (15, 3), (16, 4).
$$

This is also referred in $B47$ in Richard Guy's book *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*.